# Responsive layout & column float issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-float

I'm trying to achieve this layout with a series of tiled divs in a single row using Bootstrap 3.2.0, for screens `> 768px` wide. The div heights are either single or double, which in this sample I've set to `50px` and `100px` and div widths are controlled by class `col-sm-x`:

[image]

My best attempt so far uses the below markup & css:

**Css**

```
.red{ background-color: red; }
.blue{ background-color: blue; }
.green{ background-color: green; }
.yellow{ background-color: yellow; }
.purple{ background-color: purple; }

.home-height-single{ min-height: 50px; }
.home-height-double{ min-height: 100px; }

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .b-col {
        float: right;
    }
}
```

**Markup:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 home-height-double green">
        <p>1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 home-height-single blue b-col">
        <p>3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 home-height-single purple b-col">
        <p>2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 home-height-single green b-col">
        <p>7</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 home-height-double yellow b-col">
        <p>6</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 home-height-single blue">
        <p>4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 home-height-single red">
        <p>5</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 home-height-single red b-col">
        <p>8</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This currently produces the below, where div 8 isn't filling the gap:

[image]

### [JSFiddle - Showing the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/pUX6R/1/)

I'm aware that I could create 2 columns and wrap the divs in 2 parent divs, but I want to avoid this. The reason being that on a mobile view, I want to place divs 2 & 4 side by side, rather than have them stacked, which I don't believe I can do if the divs are wrapped in to 2 columns.

For example, I'm planning to setup my mobile view to look something like this once I've got past this issue:

[image]

Comment: You will have to customize your way in javascript using their classess

Comment: @pareshm it doesn't feel like it should be that complicated

Comment: no javascript/jquery? that seems not achievable with purely css...

Comment: you can only do it if you have a fixed height for all of your div tags, but i see you don't, so go with jquery.

Comment: I was hoping for a css only fix for this, but happy to consider jquery if all else fails.

Comment: $(function(){
    var el = $(".row div:last-child");
    el.css('top', el.height() * -1);
})

Comment: @Zafar that interferes with the elements when the width is reduced, as 8 overlaps 5.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pUX6R/3/

Comment: @Zafar that seems to do the trick, post it as an answer and I'll upvote & likely accept unless somebody comes up with some css trickery

Comment: I'd go for: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes.html. A great plugin which let's you create multiple kinds of grids. It's very easy to implement too. I had a similar problem and was able to solve it with this

Comment: @Luc think I've figured it out now, but thanks for the link, looks pretty useful

Comment: @Zafar have posted an answer to my question if you're interested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the layout issue with the following edit to my CSS media query:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .row {
        position: relative    
    }
    .b-col {
        float: right;
    }

    .b-col:last-of-type {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0
    }
}
```

### [Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pUX6R/6/)

Answer (score 2):

Do it with jQuery

```
$(function(){ 
    var el = $(".row div:last-child"); 
    el.css('top', el.height() * -1); 
    $( window ).resize(function() {
        if($( window ).width() < 768){
            el.css('top', 0); 
        }else{
            el.css('top', el.height() * -1); 
        };
    });
})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pUX6R/3/)

and let me know if you could find any css-only solution.

Answer (score -2):

Add a negative top margin to #8 and it will pop up there (-50px).

http://jsfiddle.net/72vjc/1/

```
<div style="padding: 30px; color: #ccc;">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 home-height-double green">
        <p>1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 home-height-single blue b-col">
        <p>3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 home-height-single purple b-col">
        <p>2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 home-height-single green b-col">
        <p>7</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 home-height-double yellow b-col">
        <p>6</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 home-height-single blue">
        <p>4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 home-height-single red">
        <p>5</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 home-height-single red b-col" style="margin-top:-50px">
        <p>8</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I did was look at it with another width (I did col-sm-1) which made it more narrow, but didn't move it up. That's why it looked like a margin issue to me.

Comment: what if #8's height is more than 50px?

Comment: Exactly. You would need to use javascript to calculate height and apply to other classes. You would also need to clear the negative margin for mobile.

Comment: that why i'm screaming about using jquery

Comment: Either way, if you need to calculate height, you'll need to use more than CSS.

Comment: That's just a hack to move it, I want it to live in it's rightful home not evict it from where it wants to live and force it to live where I tell it.

Comment: $(function(){
    var el = $(".row div:last-child");
    el.css('top', el.height() * -1);
})

Comment: "I want it to live in its rightful home.." That's cute.