# How to have same height for all column as biggest column which all comes in same line?

Tags: html, css

Example markup would be like this. All block in same container.

```
<div class="main">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
```

See example here. http://jsbin.com/remeci/2/edit

[image]

**In Mobile all column will be stacked to each other**

Whenever more than 1 column comes in same row, should have same height

I know if I use two .rows then I can solve this but in my current requirement I can't do that. because if first row will have only 2 wishies then 3rd block will be blank. and 1st block from 2nd row will not jump to fill that place

I don't want to use Flexbox.

Comment: Hate to say it, but a table is the easiest and simplest way.

Comment: @JonathanWood yes I know table and extra row container will do but this is not what I'm looking for

Comment: Do your child div's all need to have the same height or is it good enough to have div #5 start on the 2nd row?

Comment: Not sure if this might help, had a similar issue a while back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24448736/responsive-layout-column-float-issue

Comment: Arbel's answer is the only solution I see... If you don't want to use Flexbox  you'll have to go JS. Flexbox specs states: `In the flex layout model, the children of a flex container can be laid out in any direction, and can "flex" their sizes, either growing to fill unused space or shrinking to avoid overflowing the parent.`. Your issue relies on *filling unused space*. Flexbox was created because there was no way of doing it before!

Answer (score 1):

You made me sweat with this one, but you can change your CSS like this:

```
.col-md-3 {background:#ccc;outline:1px solid}
.sameheightRow{display:block; width:100%; overflow:hidden}
.sameheightRow .col-sm-3{display:inline-block; float:none; height:100%; margin:0; width:24%; padding:0 0 5000px; margin-bottom:-5000px; vertical-align:top; }
```

And your HTML just a tiny change (a proper name to the row so we can re-use the row later without problems, nothing else)

```
<div class="container ">
  <div class="row sameheightRow">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor ipsam consequatur voluptatum sapiente doloremque magni voluptates!</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor ipsam consequatur voluptatum sapiente. Ipsum odio voluptatum porro omnis reprehenderit veritatis vero dignissimos neque maiores ullam quam temporibus doloremque magni voluptates!</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor ipsam consequatur voluptatum sapiente. Ipsum odio voluptatum porro omnis reprehenderit veritatis vero dignissimos neque maiores ullam quam temporibus doloremque magni voluptates!</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor ipsam consequatur voluptatum sapiente.!</div>


    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor ipsam consequatur voluptatum sapiente doloremque magni voluptates!</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor ipsam consequatur voluptatum sapiente. Ipsum odio voluptatum porro omnis reprehenderit veritatis vero dignissimos neque maiores ullam quam temporibus doloremque magni voluptates!</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor ipsam consequatur voluptatum !</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor ipsam consequatur voluptatum sapiente. Ipsum odio voluptatum porro omnis reprehenderit veritatis vero dignissimos neque maiores ullam quam temporibus doloremque magni voluptates!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Of course, you'll need to adjust the width (that 25%) for smaller screens, eg 100% if you want it stacked, but you'll get the idea.

To add to the discussion on approaches to this problem, I have had similar situations which I had solved differently by using a table model, like this:

```
div style=display:table
    div style=display:table-row
        div style=display:table-cell
```

and it works beautifully as long as you can define rows, which is not your case. I have tried different approaches to this method for your situation, testing with

```
.sameheightRow .col-sm-3(4):after{/* change div behavior */}
```

but couldn't make it work, however, I'm leaving it here because it may help you if you want to test other approaches. Either way, the code I have added on top works as a charm.

Answer (score -1):

This has always been a challenge with divs, and different browsers need different solutions -- especially various iterations of IE.  The best answer AFAIK is just to use something like [Boostrap](http://getbootstrap.com/).  It includes the requisite JS and is tested to work on everything.  Its row and column elements will all properly scale as you require.

Comment: Did you noticed from the OP's demo that actually he knows already (as other mil. dev.) about bootstrap?!

Comment: I know bootstrap but what I'm asking is a different thing. Read my question. Bootstrap doesn't have readymade any solution for this

Comment: My apologies, I didn't notice.  Anyway, the solution, then is entirely JS.  You're either going to move elements from row to row, or you're going to do away with rows and detect position of each div.  i.e., iterate over each div, note the row meta-number, establish a set of maximums and then re-size.  I think a linear algebra js library would help make a matrix and then you can just use it at as operator with the dimensions.  If nobody has answered in the next hour then I will write an example.  Sorry about the laziness of my original response.