# How do I get block elements to fill out eachother?

Tags: html, css, alignment, block, element

I have got 5 elements (which should all contain content) which all should search for their own place as the browser width changes. I want them to 'fill eachother out' so there will be no whitespaces (except at the end)

[What I have right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D44Ow.png)

Picture above is what I have right now. As you see the third element is pushed down by the second.

I have five articles inside a div.
These five articles have this css:

```
width: 100%;
max-width: calc(50% - 22px);
padding: 5px;
margin: 5px;
float: left;
border: 1px solid #aaa;
background-color: #d5d5d5;
```

In short: I want the third element in my example to fill out the gap under the first element.

One solution I thought of myself was just changing the order of the different elements, but that would only clean it up a little bit, not solve the problem. (and it wouldn't work for different element lengths as they might change during time)

By the way: The content of the element is just some text. That is why the different elements have different heights, some have more text.

Comment: this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24448736/responsive-layout-column-float-issue

Comment: You are better off using columns.